# How to count the number of nodes where clicked on?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am using the d3 force layout for freetime.
At this point, I created a code, where I can click on the nodes and a tooltip pops up and returns the names of the nodes, which where clicked on.
My next step is, that I want to make the tooltip shows me a counter, that returns a counting number in the tooltip, how many nodes where clicked on.
But currently I got no idea, how to solve that problem. Hope somebody of you might help me. Thanks so much!

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
              .data(nodes)
              .enter().append("g")
              .attr("class", "node")
              .call(force.drag);

node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 19)
    .style("fill", "grey") 
    .on("click", showTooltip);        

function showTooltip(d)
{
  tooltip.text(d.name);
  tooltip.style("visibility", "visible"); 
}

var tooltip = d3.select("body")
                .append("div") 
                .attr("class", "tooltip")
                .style("position", "absolute")
                .style("z-index", "10")
                .style("visibility", "hidden");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need a variable that you increment every time a node is clicked.

```
var clickCount = 0;

function showTooltip(d) {
  clickCount++;
  tooltip.text(clickCount);
  tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, thanks so much! It works great! I wonder, why it works without a for-loop and just by using clickCount++ inside the method?

Comment: Every time you click a node, `clickCount` adds 1 to its value. It doesn't care which node was clicked, just that some node was clicked. You start out with 0 clicks. When you click the first node it increments by one so then you have 1 click. The answer would be more complicated if you only wanted to count multiple clicks on the same node one time.

Comment: now i got one more question, with this code, i can click on 2 nodes and highlight all the nodes between them... i would like to count the total highlighted number of nodes including startnode and endnode...for example, if you click on 2 nodes and there are 3 nodes between, the tooltip returns(2+3)...

Comment: `startNode= null 

    node.on("click", function(d, i) 
              {
                var path1 = startNode && startNode.path(d) || []; 
                startNode = d;
                link.style("stroke", function(d) 
                {
                  return path1.includes(d.source) && path1.includes(d.target) ? "#900" : "#999";
                });
                node.attr("r", function(d) 
                {
                  return path1.includes(d) || startNode == d ? 8 : 4.5; 
                });   `

Comment: That should be the length of your path, so `path1.length` (or `path1.length + 1` if the `startNode` is not included in `path1`).

Comment: thanks so much, and sorry that i posted the code that ugly way...i still don't kow how to paste codeblocks in the comment section...btw: `tooltip.text(path1.length)` does not work, the console say "path1 is not defined"

Comment: @DerickKolln since you're new at S.O., here is a tip: consider accepting this answer (it's a green tick on the left hand side), which gives you points! Also, consider upvoting it, as I just did. Regarding your second question, there is a reason for not having code formatting in the comments: the best practice is posting *another* question (and not asking questions in the comments) with the relevant code.